# Adding meta tags dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have different tabs, once we click on each tab the meta tags will be changed.Here I tried some code using jquery but no luck, can any one help me please
here is my code

```
 $('#idBtn').click(function(){
     $('head').append(' <meta name="description" content="Free Web tutorials"> '+'<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">'                             +'<meta name="author" content="Hege Refsnes">');
       });
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vpk5v/)

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? Those `meta` tags are only useful to search engines, and they won't find them if you add them on a click.

Comment: jsFiddle uses frames; your code works fine if you look at the correct frame.

Comment: @Blazemonger In his fiddle he's adding an `X-UA-Compatible` header, which is used by the client, and makes more sense.

Comment: @Barmar - It's only used by IE, so testing if it does indeed set the document mode when added dynamically would at least be a place to start ?

Comment: @Barmar No, it doesn't, because the `<meta>` tags are only looked at by the browser once when the page is first loaded. Anyway, the second fiddle link (in his comment) and the code posted directly in the question use SEO meta tags.

Comment: That's a different argument than "only useful to search engines".

Comment: @Rajasekhar Can you use server side language ? to add it ?

Answer (score 1):

What you do is completely wrong. Because meta tags should be persistent content, available in the DOM. What you do is also useless, because you inject the meta after the DOM was loaded, so it's just temporary injected